# How convert Persian date to Gregorian in R?

Tags: r, date

I want to convert a  Persian calendar date (e.g. 1399/03/27) to a Gregorian calendar date in R. Is there any function to do so in R?

Comment: See if function [ConvCalendar::OtherDate](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ConvCalendar/versions/1.2/topics/OtherDate) solves the problem.

Comment: @Rui Barradas,  ConvCalendar package is not available now. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 4):

As *@RuiBarradas* pointed out in comments, we may use `ConvCalendar::OtherDate`. Since the package is no longer on CRAN we first need to install it from source:

```
# p.url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/ConvCalendar/ConvCalendar_1.2.tar.gz"
# install.packages(p.url,
#                  repos=NULL, type="source")
```

`OtherDate` wants day, month, and year separately in a vector and in this order. It creates a list-like object of class `"OtherDate"` that can be fed into `as.Date` to return Gregorian date.

```
library(ConvCalendar)
persian <- OtherDate(day=27, month=03, year=1399, calendar="persian")
gregorian <- as.Date(persian)
gregorian
# [1] "2020-06-16"
```

More automatically we may use `do.call`.

```
persian <- "1399/03/27"
persian <- do.call(OtherDate, c(as.list(rev(el(strsplit(persian, "/")))), 
                                calendar="persian"))
gregorian <- as.Date(persian)
gregorian
# [1] "2020-06-16"
```

Comment: ConvCalendar package is not available now. Is there another way to do it?(After I install is offline, I got following error Error: library(ConvCalendar) package or namespace load failed for ‘ConvCalendar’:
 package ‘ConvCalendar’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it)

Comment: @Masoud Install from source as shown in answer, it still works, just tested.

Comment: Thanks, how to convert from "gregorian" to "persian"? (inverse convert "2020-06-16" to "1399/03/27"?

Comment: @Masoud Try `paste(as.OtherDate("2020-06-16","persian")[3:1], collapse='/')`.

Comment: @Masoud Or `do.call(sprintf, c(as.OtherDate("2020-06-16", "persian")[3:1], fmt='%d/%02d/%02d'))` to get the leading zeroes.