# Convert Persian dates to Gregorian dates (also inverse convert)

Tags: r, date

How to convert Persian dates to Gregorian dates? For example:

```
 '1400/04/09' --->'2021-06-30'
```

and how to do inverse conversion.

```
 '1400/04/09' <---'2021-06-30'
```

I found [how-convert-persian-date-to-gregorian-in-r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62455880/how-convert-persian-date-to-gregorian-in-r) but unfortunately the 'ConvCalendar' package that used in the answer, is not available. I manually downloaded it and installed it but I got following error

```
  > library("ConvCalendar")
  Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ConvCalendar’:
  package ‘ConvCalendar’ was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
```

Is there any other package that convert Persian dates to Gregorian dates in R?

Comment: Installing from source, as shown in linked answer still works, just tested now.